# discord embed форматирование

Tags: python, discord.py

я пытаюсь форматировать строку в embed, но у меня ничего не получается.
Форматирование строк почему то работает только в  `emb.add_field`, но это не совсем мне подходит.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def info(self, ctx):
        emb = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.red(),title='Все  команды отправляются с префиксом <q>')
        emb.set_footer(text='*** my text ***')
        await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в `footer` нельзя использовать форматирование текста

Comment: А есть какие то альтернативные варианты помимо `emb.add_field`,поскольку он переносит строку

Comment: Можно всё писать в `description`